# Unable to call custom annotation in selenium test

Tags: java, selenium, junit, annotations, apache-poi

Unable to call custom annotation in selenium test
i am writing a Apache poi selenium junit test - 
To avoid @RunWith i have tried myown annotation

```
public class MyTest extends OtherTest {
    String a ;
    String b;
    String c;
    String d;

   @testDataProvider(name = "abc")
    public static Object[][] fetchClass(){
        Object[][] ar = excel.getar("abc");
        return (ar);
    }

    @testDataProviderTest(dataProvider = "abc")
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Custom annotation class for testDataProvider, I have tried to use same testng DataProvider in the Custom annotation as below

```
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface testDataProvider {
    public String name() default "";
    boolean parallel() default false;
    int[] indices() default {};
}
```

Custom annotation for testDataPrviderTest

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface testDataProviderTest {
    public String[] groups() default {};
    public boolean enabled() default true;
    @Deprecated
    public String[] parameters() default {};
    public String[] dependsOnGroups() default {};
    public String[] dependsOnMethods() default {};
    public long timeOut() default 0;
    public long invocationTimeOut() default 0;
    public int invocationCount() default 1;
    public int threadPoolSize() default 0;
    public int successPercentage() default 100;
    public String dataProvider() default "";
    public Class<?> dataProviderClass() default Object.class;
    public boolean alwaysRun() default false;
    public String description() default "";
    public Class[] expectedExceptions() default {};
    public String expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp() default ".*";
    public String suiteName() default "";
    public String testName() default "";
    public boolean sequential() default false;
    public boolean singleThreaded() default false;
    public Class retryAnalyzer() default Class.class;
    public boolean skipFailedInvocations() default false;
    public boolean ignoreMissingDependencies() default false;
    int priority() default 0;

}
```

I am avoiding to use @RunWith as I have Before method to fetch the path of Excel sheet.